# Can UNet be used to do image-to-image predictions?

Tags: image, deep-learning, regression, prediction, unet-neural-network

For example, I have a series of image data like temprature, albedo and NDVI, and I want to use deep learning method to do image-to-image prediction, or specifically speaking, image-to-image regression task.

The formula of the task is like :

> Any Predictions (it is an image) = Model<sub>Deep learning</sub>(Temp, Abledo, NDVI)

Can UNet be used to do this? If possible, how to do it in practice? And is there any other deep learning model able to complete this task?

I've tried this in Random Forest, in these process, the task can be performed in an numpy series like this picture indicates:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuwGy.png)

Just to transform the output from 1-D numpy series to 2-D image, and the image-to-image prediction can be done. But i am not familiar with how to use UNet or some models like this to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess yes. You can see in the paper how they have used U-Net for image denoising and enhancement.
Git Link: https://github.com/cchen156/Learning-to-See-in-the-Dark
Paper: https://cchen156.github.io/paper/18CVPR_SID.pdf